# If OR statement not working properly

Tags: java, if-statement

Almost embarrassed to ask this, but I can't seem to find the problem...

I got this statement:

```
if (name_region.matches("")){
   System.out.println("He shows this");
}

if (region.contains(name_region.substring(0, 2))||(firstLine == true)||(name_region.matches(""))){
   System.out.println("he doesn't show this");
}
```

He passes the first one, but not the second one.
While I think it also should pass the second one, because it is an OR statement right?

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Does `name_region.substring(0, 2)` throw any Exception ?

Comment: paste the value of name_region as well

Comment: @TheNewIdiot ah! you are right, forgot to add post a log in my Exception... It does throw an Exception, that is why it isn't working ofcourse... Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `name_region.substring(0, 2)` is throwing an Exception . Try to rearrange the expressions in the `if()` :

```
if (name_region.matches("")||
    region.contains(name_region.substring(0, 2))||
    firstLine){
   System.out.println("he doesn't show this");
}
```

`||` is short circuit `OR` operator , hence if the first expression is `true` , the others won't be evaluated .

Comment: Yes, but if the first one is true, then the "he doesn't show this" strings will be logged and it doesn't as I understand.

Comment: Because he has put that expression as the last one !

Comment: He is right. For an or statement you only need one condition to be true. If you use ||, he will not check the other conditions, because he already knows the answer is true. If you still want to check the other condtions, use |

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Thanks, I actually didn't knew it worked that way: `||` is short circuit `OR` operator , hence if the first expression is `true` , the others won't be evaluated . Learned something new again.